# Questions about linear independent and spanning set and basis

Tags: linear-algebra

True or false? Given reason

1. A set of 5 Vectors in R5 must be a basis for R5  (R5 means 5th dimensional space)
2. A set of 6 Vectors in R5 cannot be a basis for R5
3. A set of 7 vectors in R5 must be a spanning set for R5
4. A set of 6 polynomials in R5 must be a basis for R5
5. A set of 6 polynomials in R5 may be a basis for R5

Anyone help me to explain these question.. I want to know the reason cz it's confused me a lot and i always get mess about these kind of question
appericated it!

Comment: To get you started:  try "degenerate" cases.  For the first one, say, suppose all $5$ vectors were the zero vector $(0,0,0,0,0)$.  Nothing in the statement excludes that case...would that be a basis for $\mathbb R^5$?

Comment: What in the world is a polynomial in $\Bbb R^5$?

Comment: @lulu: "A set of $5$ vectors in $\Bbb R^5$" surely means a subset of $\Bbb R^5$ having $5$ elements, no?

Comment: @CameronBuie  Nothing in the statement says that the vectors have to be distinct.  Of course, we can add that condition if we want (doesn't change the answer).  As to the polynomial...I'm guessing but it seems likely that the OP means to identify $\mathbb R^5$ with the space of quartic polynomials with real coefficients.  I agree that the statements are too vague to be sure of anything.

Comment: @lulu: The word "set" indicates that they must be distinct, for if not, then it is a set of *one* vector. I suspect you're right about the polynomials.

Comment: @David: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? The more you can tell us about your thoughts and efforts, the better we can tailor answers to your needs. We can't very well do that, knowing only that you have trouble with this sort of question.

Comment: David,  If you are to follow the suggestion of @CameronBuie  (and it sounds sensible enough), then you are to assume that in each question the collection (of vectors or polynomials) are distinct.  In that case, my degenerate example is too degenerate (all $5$ vectors are the same) but other degenerate example work fine.  (e.g. $(n,n,n,n,n)$ for $n\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: @CameronBuie yes u r right. It means a subset of R5 having 5 elements.Actually we can choose any 5 vectors we want but we need  to use them to prove whether the statement is right or not. For polynomials, the element in subset is the real coefficients of each degree. R5 means the highest degree of polynomials is 5.

Comment: @David: I suspect the highest degrew should be $4,$ not $5,$ since there is a constant term, too.

Answer (score 1):

1) False: Use the zero vector and any other 4 vectors. 
2) True: For a set of vectors to be a basis, all vectors must be linearly independent. It's not possible to have 6 linearly independent vectors in R5 (max is 5 linearly independent vectors). 
3) False: Pick any vector $v$, then $2v, 3v, 4v, 5v, 6v, 7v$. These do not span R5. 
4) Not sure what this means, R5 is a vector space, not a function space. 
5) Same as 4.

Comment: Great first answer! Keep up the good work! +1 from me